# Form and Results in the same activity with different fragments

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-listview, android-asynctask

I try to populate a list view with results from the web and would like to know if my approach is relevant. I created an activity with 2 attached fragments.
**MainActivity** *[Form Fragment, Results Fragment]*

**JSON Response**
{"id":"abc","name":"John","cars":2,"avatar":"url.com/john.jpg"},{"id"...}

**Form Fragment**
Displays a form with 1 input and 1 button. As soon as the button is clicked, an *asynctask* is launched to retrieve the json from the web. During this process, a *loading dialog* is opened.
I then parse the json into *HashMap(String, Object)* and push them into an *ArrayList*.
*onPostExecute*, I send the *ArrayList* to the *Activity* within an *interface* and close the loading dialog.

**Results Fragment**
I would like to open this *fragment* once the *asynctask* is finished, retrieve the *ArrayList* from the *Activity* and display it with a *SimpleAdapter*.
From here i would also like to launch another *asynctask* to load avatar images from the web (i don't care if images are loaded gradually, i just don't want to slow down the display since text is the essential part and images anecdotal)

What do you think of this approach, instead of using 2 separate activities.
Thank you in advance from a newbie of android programming